# print average and the cost per liter in the text file using python

Tags: python, math, text-files, average

I'm trying to get the average of the cost value and the cost per liter.

```
r = []
with open('petrolPrice.txt') as f1:
    r = f1.read()
    s = r.split()
    del s[0]
    s.pop(0)
    
    print(sum(s) / len(s)) # AVERAGE COST
    
with open('petrolPrice.txt') as f1:
    r = f1.read()
    s = r.split()
    s.pop(0)
    
    # COST PER LITER
```

Here is the text file below. The liters and cost are divided using tab space

```
Liters  Cost
20.0    56.40
9.6 29.95
5.0 15.60
15.0    54.30
18.4    65.32
18.7    75.36
17.7    80.00
```

print average and the cost per liter in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
with open("input.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    #get first value of every line as Liters 
    liters = [(line.split()[0]) for line in lines if line.split()[0] != 'Liters']
    #get second value of every line as Cost
    cost = [(line.split()[1]) for line in lines if line.split()[1] != 'Cost']
    #df with Liters and Cost
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Liters': liters, 'Cost': cost})
    #add column with cost per liter
    df['Cost per liter'] = df['Cost'].astype(float) / df['Liters'].astype(float)
    #add row with mean
    df.loc[len(liters)] = [df['Liters'].astype(float).mean(), df['Cost'].astype(float).mean(), df['Cost per liter'].astype(float).mean()]
    #df to text
    df.to_csv('output.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Open the file reading one line at a time. Skip the first line. Convert the two (expected) whitespace delimited tokens to float. Sum the values. Do a final calculation.

```
totalLitres = 0
totalCost = 0

with open('petrolPrice.txt') as pp:
    next(pp) # skip heading
    for line in pp:
        litres, cost = map(float, line.split())
        totalLitres += litres
        totalCost += cost
    print(f'Average cost per litre = {totalCost/totalLitres:.2f}')
```

**Output:**

```
Average cost per litre = 3.61
```